# Django template tag search through for-loop looking for specific object with default if not found

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm passing a queryset of people to my django template, some of which have been assigned a "seat" and others that haven't. Seats can be assigned to no one and therefore remain empty. For each seat, I want the template to loop through the queryset looking for someone in that seat. If the for loop doesn't find anyone for that seat, I want them to render an empty seat. Here is what I was thinking:

```
{% for person in people %}
    {% if person.seat_num = 1 %}
        <div class="filled_seat"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <div class="empty_seat"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Except I realize that {% empty %} is only triggered if the set being iterated through is empty, whereas I need to have a default if the seat is not found (aka nothing in the set survives the "if" condition.

Comment: It might work better to generate `filled_seats` and `empty_seats` querysets in the view and pass them into the template, instead of doing so much calculation in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Gordon's comment made me realize I shouldn't try to do too much in the template itself. In the view I created a list called "seats" and filled the appropriate seats, and then passed it to the template:

```
seats = []
    for n in range(4):
        try:
            seats.append(students.objects.get(seat_num=n+1))
        except:
            seats.append(None)
```

---

I then used a for loop to cycle through the seats one at a time and check if that seat is filled and then generate the appropriate div:

```
{% for seat in seats %}
    <td>
    {% if seat %}
        <div class="filled_seat"></div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="empty_seat"></div>
    {% endif %}                        
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because [for...empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) works like that. It basically can't know if your seat is empty or not, for that you need to implement your own logic.

I don't know the details of your model, but guessing from your example you need to do something like this:

```
 {% for person in people %}
    {% if person.seat_num = 0 %}
      <div class="empty_seat"></div> 
    {% else %}
      <div class="filled_seat"></div> 
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's what I thought of first, but the problem with that is that it will generate an empty_seat div for each person not in seat 1, whereas I want the end result to be a single "filled_seat" div or a single "empty_seat" div.

Comment: What does a person without a seat has in seat_num according to your model?

Comment: I made an update, so if person has no seat (I assumed it's 0) it's empty or else filled. You get the idea, logic depends on how you represent empty seat in your model (which I don't know)